# Detect usage of macro? (errno)

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

This is very specific, and a bit difficult to explain, and quite likely impossible, but here goes.

I want to implement **<errno.h>**. (My hobby project is implementing a Standard **C** library.)

The naïve way to go about it is:

```
// in <errno.h>
extern int errno;

// in some .c file
int errno = 0;
```

This works. But it has one disadvantage: If a math library function is called, it *always* has to query the FPU status after execution to set `errno` as appropriate. This stalls the FPU in math-heavy applications.

The **C** standard endorses lazy evaluation of `errno` by making it a macro instead:

```
int * __errno();
#define errno *__errno()
```

This way, `errno` is only "set" when its value is actually requested:

```
// "__errno()" returns the location of the current errno value,
// the "errno" macro turns it into a value.
x = errno;
```

Given some logic in the rest of the library, the FPU status needs only be queried if the last library function called was actually one *using* the FPU, *and the value of `errno` is actually requested*.

So far, everything is fine. But it's the other way around that is giving me headaches:

```
errno = 0;
```

The value of `errno` is not requested at all. *But `__errno()` does not know that, and will query the FPU status if the last library function called was using the FPU.*

Right now I don't see a way to avoid that (i.e., have the `errno` macro or the `__errno()` function somehow work differently depending on whether they are used to the left or the right of the assignment operator), and am almost content to accept this.

But perhaps any of you SO'ers has a brilliant idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No brilliant ideas here, but afaik `errno` is allowed to be implemented via function calls to make thread-safe implementations of the standard library possible. I don't think querying the FPU lazily is a good idea: How will you avoid inconsistency in situations like this:

- set `errno`
- floating-point ops which set error flags
- get `errno`
- get flags

Should a call to `__errno()` clear the flags or not?

According to the standard, whether or not `errno` has to be set by math functions is determined by the value of `math_errhandling` (specifically, `math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO`).

What I would do is make the error reporting optional via preprocessor directives and allow the programmer to set the value of `math_errhandling` at compile time. This would mean that the math functions can't be compiled statically beforehand but have to reside in a header, which might be a good idea anyway to allow compilers without link-time optimizations to inline these functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is a fairly good analysis of why the whole `errno` mechanism is so unsatisfactory.  You could find a similar analysis in Kernighan's "The Standard C Library" too.

The functional form of `errno` is also needed for thread-safe implementations, where different threads have separate error values accessed via a thread-specific `errno`.

Your macro should probably have parentheses around it for safety:

```
#define errno (*__errno())
```

Answer (score 1):

More a comment than an answer, but without code formatting it would not be understandable.

If you check lazily the FPU flags, how would you have the correct behavior here (the math functions are special in that they are guaranteed not to modify errno when there is no problem)?

```
errno = 0;
x = acos(y);
z = <exp>;
if (errno != 0) {
   /* can't come here even if y is a valid argument but <exp> modified the flags if it didn't call any functions */
}
```